# The EXE file made in Pyinstaller does not start, although everything works in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, exe, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

Code (partial):

```
#coding=utf-8
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import zipfile
## import markup

def main():

layout = [.........
```

it is written in python3. 9. 0 and runs the interface with buttons.The PySimpleGUI library is used for this. Next, I make an EXE file using Pyinstaller. Did in Mac and Windows-exe-shnik does not start. It doesn't give any errors. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem with pyinstaller before. I hope this will be able to help you.

First, create your .exe with pyinstaller using: `pyinstaller -F yourscript.py`

Then try launching your .exe. There should be a debug window that opens and will display an error right before it closes. I was able to screenshot this window right before the program quit and found that I was having problems importing some random package. For me, pyinstaller wasn't importing `pkg_resources.py2_warn` so I added `import pkg_resources.py2_warn` in my imports and used pyinstaller again.

Then my .exe worked.

Best of luck!